# splitting an integration in two parts

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have an integration and I am splitting this one in two parts ;

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a-b}=\int_{0}^{a}+\int_{a}^{a-b}=\int_{0}^{a}-\int_{a-b}^{a}$

and

$\displaystyle a\geq b$

Is it correct to write this integral in two part like this ?
The fact that bothers me is that I make the split on $a$ which is for sure greater then $a-b$.

Comment: the first equality is hard to believe, $\int_0^{a}+\int_{a}^{a-b}=\int_a^b \neq \int_0^{a-b}$...

Comment: I did not write $\int_{0}^{a}+\int_{a}^{a-b}=\int_{a}^{b}$ above.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just mix the stuff. It's obvious that

$$ \int_0^a = \int_0^{a-b} + \int_{a-b}^a$$

Therefore, using the usual $\int_c^d = -\int_d^c$,

$$\int_0^{a-b} = \int_{0}^a - \int_{a-b}^a = \int_0^a + \int_{a}^{a-b}$$

Comment: Thank you, so I suppose it is correct what I have written above.

Comment: Yes, it is correct